# What is the role of abstract machines in the Curry-Howard isomorphism?

Tags: reference-request, logic, computation-models, curry-howard

By [abstract machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_machine) I mean things like the SECD machine, Krivine's machine or more generally machines with states/memory/registers/stack/accumulator...

According to Wikipedia page of the [Curry-Howard isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), we have a correspondence with the Sequent Calculus where the left/right introductions rule matches with the constructors of codes and evaluation stacks. And the priority of rules application is related to call-by-value and call-by name reduction.

So I'm looking for more information than what we can find in Wikipedia.

Comment: Wikipedia lists a number of references. The Griffin, Parigot and Herbelin references are classic. I would recommend reading those first.

Comment: Starting with [A Functional Correspondence between Evaluators and Abstract Machines](http://www.brics.dk/RS/03/Abs/BRICS-RS-03-Abs/BRICS-RS-03-Abs.html#BRICS-RS-03-13), there's been a string of work that directly connects abstract machines with evaluators. I've collected many (spiritual) successors [here](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2423#comment-38384). Roughly speaking, given a Curry-Howard correspondence between a language and a logic, you can then use this approach to further get a correspondence to a *particular* abstract machine derived from an evaluator for the language.